# ActiveMQ Spring listener suddently stops working

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic

I have to fix an inherited application from another company, and I have an error which is not clear to me: the jms listener stops working suddently without any evident reason.

It's a spring-based client, here is the context:

```
    <bean id="amqConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" >
    <property name="useAsyncSend" value="false" />
    <property name="useCompression" value="true" />
    <property name="optimizeAcknowledge" value="true" />
    <property name="messagePrioritySupported" value="true" />
    <property name="brokerURL" value="failover:(tcp://${brokerHost}:61616)?timeout=3000&jms.redeliveryPolicy.maximumRedeliveries=-1&jms.redeliveryPolicy.maximumRedeliveryDelay=1000000&jms.redeliveryPolicy.useExponentialBackOff=true" />
    <property name="maxThreadPoolSize" value="60" />
    <property name="closeTimeout" value="2000" />
    <property name="nonBlockingRedelivery" value="true" />
    <property name="exclusiveConsumer" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory"  class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory" >
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="amqConnectionFactory" /> 
    <property name="maxConnections" value="50" />
    <property name="maximumActiveSessionPerConnection" value="100" />
    <property name="idleTimeout" value="20000" />
    <property name="expiryTimeout" value="15000" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate" abstract="true">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="explicitQosEnabled" value="true"/>
    <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true" />
    <property name="sessionAcknowledgeModeName" value="CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE" />
    <property name="receiveTimeout" value="4000" />
</bean>

<bean id="actionsJmsTemplate" parent="jmsTemplate">
    <property name="defaultDestination" ref="actionPendingDestination"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsActionsListenerContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="destination" ref="actionPendingDestination"/>
    <property name="messageSelector" value="" />
    <property name="messageListener" ref="actionsListener" />
    <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true"/>
    <property name="cacheLevelName" value="CACHE_SESSION" />
    <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="50" />
    <!-- <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" /> -->
    <property name="transactionTimeout" value="1000" />
</bean>

<!--  ActiveMQ Destinations -->
<bean id="actionPendingDestination" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="actions.pending.queue.>"/>
```

The bean "actionsListener", which handles the messages inside the app, implements javax.jms.MessageListener and org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNameAware. And it doesn't do anything like acknowledge the session or manage a transaction. There's no code like that in that class.

The versions of the libraries are:

- Spring: 3.2.5.RELEASE
- ActiveMQ client: 5.9
- JDK: 1.6

Do you see any problem with this configuration?

Thanks!

Carlos

Comment: How many messages get processed before it stops working?

Answer (score 0):

I see it's using CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE; have you confirmed that the ack happens on all code paths (including exceptions)?  It's been a while, but I think what happens if you don't ack messages is that you can only process your prefetch buffer worth, so once you fail to make that number of acks, you're done.

Comment: That's what I suspect, although I'm not sure if this is handled somehow by Spring. Also, as you can see, the session is transacted, and I'm not sure if that affects the acknowledge mode... I'll take a look at the prefect buffer as soon as we can start the system, this only happens in production, so it's a bit tricky :S Thanks!

Comment: If you can find a way to reproduce it consistently in a test environment, you could try setting the ack mode to AUTO_ACK just to see if that fixed the problem.  (That'll at least confirm whether the problem is a failure to ack messages.)

Comment: How can I check a consumer's prefetch buffer size? Also, a consumer with a full prefetch buffer counts as a concurrent consumer? If that is so, if just 10 consumers get their buffers full they'd block the message consumption.

Comment: You can use a JMX viewer (such as JConsole) to look at the number of dispatched messages for a given consumer; if messages are backed up on the broker, then you know that the client's prefetch buffer is full, so the number of messages currently dispatched to it is equal to its prefetch buffer size.